# rosout keeps respawning even after killall

Tags: ros, rosout, rosnode, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am working on automating my experiment runs and hence need to kill all nodes periodically. I am using `rosnode kill -a` at the moment, but the `rosout` process keeps re-spawning all the time. I have indicated in my launch file that all the nodes have a `respawn="false"` argument. Does anybody know which this could be happening?

I issue the `rosnode kill -a` from a python script which I used to automate my runs as

```
os.system('rosnode kill --all')
```

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131046/rosout-keeps-respawning-even-after-killall/) by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1295 on 2014-02-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rosout` node is part of `roscore`. If you really need to shut it down, you will have to kill `roscore` too.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) with karma: 411 on 2014-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) on 2014-02-24**:
Already tried that, but the respawn is still persistent.

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2014-02-24**:
As I said, `rosout` is part of `roscore`. You can not have the latter without the former. Out of curiosity, how is `rosout` a concern to you?